# How many peas one can win

Tags: proof-verification, contest-math

$A$ and $B$ plays the following game. In a table there are $n>1$ plates which are empty at the beginning. In the beginning of every round, $A$ moves some plates to the right hand side of the board, and the rest to the left hand side of the board. $B$ chooses the plates on the some side of the board and adds a pea to every plate that is on the side of the board he chose. Then, in the same turn, $B$ bails out the plates on the other side of the board. $A$ can end the game and count the peas she has on one plate, or else a new round starts. Show that if $B$ chooses the optimal strategy*, $A$ can win at most n-1 peas.

*I guess it means the strategy which minimizes the number of peas A has in the end but that was not given in the problem.

Is the following proof valid? Is there another proofs?

Let $S$ be the number of peas. At the begging, $S=0$. Now, we will prove that if in some moment $S$ is less than $n$, then it will again be less than $n$. Now,the number of all peas if B adds to both sides will be $S+n\leq 2n-1$, so $B$ can pick a one that has less than $n$, so we are finished.

This is from http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=615043 but I can't follow it and say if the proof is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is correct, though it could be explained more clearly. Suppose that at $A$ has just moved the plates, and it’s $B$’s turn. Suppose further that $p$, the total number of peas on all $n$ plates, is less than $n$. Now $B$ imagines adding one pea to every plate on the table, not just the plates on the righthand side. There are then altogether $n+p<n+n=2n$ peas on the table. Let $\ell$ be the total number of peas on the lefthand side, and let $r$ be the total number of peas on the righthand side. Then $\ell+r=n+p<2n$, so at least one of the numbers $\ell$ and $r$ must be less than $n$. (If $\ell\ge n$ **and** $r\ge n$, then $\ell+r\ge 2n$, which we know is false.)

If $\ell<n$, $B$ chooses the lefthand side. After he adds a pea to each plate on that side, there are $\ell$ peas there, and after he clears the plates on the other side of the table, there are $\ell$ peas on the table altogether. Thus, the total number of peas on the table is still less than $n$.

Otherwise, $B$ chooses the righthand side, and after he adds a pea to each plate on that side and clears the plates on the other side, there are $r$ peas on the table. But he chose the righthand side because $\ell\ge n$, so $r<n$, and once again we see that the total number of peas on the table is less than $n$.

Thus, if $B$ plays intelligently, he can always arrange to leave fewer than $n$ peas on the table at the end of his turn. This means that $B$ cannot possibly get more than $n-1$ peas no matter when she stops the game.